# dash-to-dock Ubuntu 22.04 sorting order of windows in previw

Tags: gnome, unity-dash, dash-to-dock

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop.
I've dash-to-dock installed on it and customized a few things.
When I click on a running app on the dash-to-dock, it shows an overview of the running windows.
I usually have some instances/windows of Firefox running.
Whenever I start the laptop and restore the Firefox session, all the windows get reopened.
When I click on the Firefox icon on the dash-to-panel, I get the preview of open windows, but every time, the windows are sorted in another way, so the window that was on the top of the preview last time this time is somewhere below.
I find this behavior inconvenient. Whenever I restart the laptop, I must search the whole dash-to-dock preview to find the window I want to dive into.
I have been searching for a solution or workaround, but I didn't find anything.
I also tried dconf but did not see any configuration related to the sorting order.
Is there a way to define a sorting order in a single app's preview of open windows?